# Using a button in android to display 1 of 3 different lines of text in sequence, then different ones the next day

Tags: java, android, button

I'm trying to make an app that displays a line of text, with a button below it.  When you push the "next" button, it will display a second line of text where the first was, then a third, and after that it will loop back to the first.  When tomorrow rolls around, I would like it to display a new set of lines of text, and so on.

So lets say I have 9 lines of text.  On day one, I would like the button to automatically display line 1, then upon button press line 2, then 3, then to loop back to line one and so on.  On day two, I would like it to automatically display line 4, then on button press line 5, then 6.  On day three, line 7, then 8 then 9.

I am an absolute noob in java so far, so all help and explanation is greatly appreciated.

So far I'm playing around with using Day_Of_Month, but really i have little idea how to get it all together.  Someone suggested a datafile with all my sentences in it, as I'd like to update the list of lines once a month without having to meticulously update code each month.

Comment: I suggest, since you're "an absolute noob", that you take the proper steps in learning *Java* (at least to the intermediate level), *then* look at Android, *then* get funky with it. Questions like these are not the focus of so. It's far too broad. Come with questions about specific problems that you have code, error messages, and attempted fix/try-s for.

Comment: thanks for the info - I'm rather new in general to java and android, I'm currently learning java from a udemy course and thought that this idea would be an easy start, and have had trouble finding an online forum to get answers to noob like broad questions.  I dont need someone to write all the code for me, but could use someone to point me in the right direction of the general layout that would be most efficient so i dont end up having to update a crazy amount of code every month.  Is there a site you could recommend for someone in my position to get help at this level?

Comment: I can tell you this, if you code the program right, there won't be any continuous-monthly code updating, aside from a db, or file as you said, of sentences to display. Start off small. Get the app up and running showing one sentence, try to add another and so on. Along the way, if you encounter problems, ask questions. You'll find many are already answered.

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like this to check which day it is, and do something according to that day. This just an sample code & it can be improved. The actions you do, like add an text of line are easy to do, you just have to create an textview programmatically.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.Calendar;

/**
 * Created by ionut.negru on 6/3/2014.
 */
public class DifferentDays extends Activity {

    // Could be an enum for better performance, or something else...
    private static final int
            DAY_ONE = 1,
            DAY_TWO = 2,
            DAY_THREE = 3,
            DAY_FOUR = 4,
            DAY_FIVE = 5,
            DAY_SIX = 6,
            DAY_SEVEN = 7,
            DAY_EIGHT = 8,
            DAY_NINE = 9;

    // Use Calendar instead of Date, because Date is deprecated
    private Calendar startDate;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (firstRun()) {
            // Set first run
            setFirstRun();
        }
        // Update the start date each time the activity is created
        startDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        startDate.setTimeInMillis(getStartDate());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume () {
        super.onResume();

        int startDay = startDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int currentDay = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        final int DAY = checkDay(startDay, currentDay);
        switch (startDay) {
            case DAY_ONE:
                // Do something for day one
                break;
            case DAY_TWO:
                // Do something for day two
                break;
            case DAY_THREE:
                // Do something for day three
                break;
            case DAY_FOUR:
                // Do something for day four
                break;
            case DAY_FIVE:
                // Do something for day five
                break;
            case DAY_SIX:
                // Do something for day six
                break;
            case DAY_SEVEN:
                // Do something for day seven
                break;
            case DAY_EIGHT:
                // Do something for day eight
                break;
            case DAY_NINE:
                // Do something for day nine
                break;
            default:
                // current day, or other days
                break;

        }

    }

    /**
     * Check if this is the first run
     *
     * @return {@code true} if it is the first run
     */
    private boolean firstRun () {
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        int lastFirstRun = prefs.getInt("last_run", 0);

        return lastFirstRun < versionCode();

    }

    /**
     * The application's version code.
     *
     * @return The version code
     */
    private int versionCode () {
        int versionCode = 1;
        try {
            versionCode = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(),
                                                             PackageManager.GET_META_DATA).versionCode;
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), e.getCause() == null ? e.getMessage()
                    : e.getCause().toString());
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            // Nothing to do
        }
        return versionCode;
    }

    private void setFirstRun () {
        // Update the version code
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putInt("last_run", versionCode());
        editor.putLong("start_date", Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
        editor.commit();
    }

    private long getStartDate () {
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        return prefs.getLong("start_date", 0);
    }

    /**
     * Get the day number. Will get the difference between current day & start day.
     *
     * @param startDay
     * @param currentDay
     *
     * @return
     */
    private int checkDay (final int startDay, final int currentDay) {
        int day;
        if (startDay > currentDay) {
            // something is wrong or it is current day
            day = 0;
        } else {
            day = currentDay - startDay;
        }
        return day;
    }
}
```

Hope it will help you achieve what you want, best regards.

Comment: Did you guys have the same idea or did you actually code this up for op?

Comment: Can you further explain @BobbyDigital ? I just wanted to help him with what he wanted to achieve. I covered the basic idea on how he can identify which day it is and to initialize the start date only once... After that he can add the actions he wants and further improve the code.
I just wrriten this in 5 minutes and it is just to help him.

Comment: You're are free to do what you wish; I was just curious if you coded this specifically to answer this question. I don't believe providing code for a question that shows zero understanding or effort is of the best interest of anyone. It perpetuates further poor questions by the user, and others, who in turn never learn anything.

Comment: Well that is your opinion. IMOH, I gave the user a basic idea on how he could detect which day he is in; a way to correctly initialize the starting date; a way to take custom actions based on the day; and also an idea on how he can add/remove TextViews(If he wants, I'll add a snippet of code to show him how he can achieve this).

Comment: thanks for your input ionut - I really am a total noob at this and have been looking for somewhere to ask questions of this sort, this site is the closest I could find to what I was looking for.  I hadn't even considered having to check if it was the first run or to check for versions, so you've definitely given me more to look up.  Again thanks for the help, if you know somewhere that I'd be able to ask more beginner broad general questions like this and not step on peoples feet it would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: If you want to learn more about Android you can check tutorial websites like http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/android.html, he has some nice tutorials and you will start with the basic. He also has JAVA tutorials, here http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/java.html.
These will cover your basic learning for Android or JAVA. There are many more websites like these you can try, if you want more I'll post more links.
Also for Android, you should also check the official page http://developer.android.com/index.html

Comment: I originally started on a video series of 200 videos on thenewboston but soon realized it was from 2011, and didn't want to continue there in case it was outdated (no point in learning something obsolete).  Any links you have would be greatly appreciated, as looking for something not only relevant but also up to date and well written has been a bit hard to find.

Comment: You can start with the tutorials from the oficial page:
http://developer.android.com/training/index.html
You can also search for Tutorial Books from Wrox, for Android, it also has code samples & snippets.
Android Hive - http://www.androidhive.info/, can also help you learn more.
Android SDK also has some samples, they all have comments & java-docs, check them out to see how things work in Android.
If you go through all these tutorials you will get the hang of Android Environment and you can develop good application.
I wish you the best.
Btw, if the code helped you, you can mark it as an answer